Parameter curves are geodesic then $E_v=G_u = 0$
I'm trying to solve question $\text{4/II/12G}$ of this pdf:
A special case $F=0$ of this question is proved in another post

For $(\text{i})$:
The tangent vector to the unit-speed curve $u=c$ is $\frac{X_v}{\sqrt{G}}$
By assumption the $v$-parameter curve $u=c$ is a geodesic, so $(\frac{X_v}{\sqrt{G}})_v$ is normal to the surface, so
$$(\frac{X_v}{\sqrt{G}})_v\cdot X_u=0$$
so
$$(\frac{F}{\sqrt{G}})_v=(\frac{X_v}{\sqrt{G}}\cdot X_u)_v=\frac{X_v}{\sqrt{G}}\cdot X_{uv}=\frac{G_v}{2\sqrt{G}}=(\sqrt{G})_v$$
Similarly, the $u$-parameter curve $v=d$ is a geodesic, so $(\frac{X_u}{\sqrt{E}})_u$ is normal to the surface, so
$$(\frac{X_u}{\sqrt{E}})_u\cdot X_v=0$$
so
$$(\frac{F}{\sqrt{E}})_u=(\frac{X_u}{\sqrt{E}}\cdot X_v)_u=\frac{X_u}{\sqrt{E}}\cdot X_{uv}=\frac{E_v}{2\sqrt{E}}=(\sqrt{E})_v$$

For $(\text{ii})$:
By assumption the angle $\alpha$ betwen $u=c,v=d$ is independent of $c$ and $d$, so $F/\sqrt{EG}=\cos\alpha$ is independent of $u$ and $v$.
From $(\text{i})$ I get $(F / \sqrt{G})_v=(\sqrt{G})_u$ and $(F / \sqrt{E})_u=(\sqrt{E})_v$.
so $\cos\alpha\cdot(\sqrt{E})_v=(\sqrt{G})_u$ and $\cos\alpha\cdot(\sqrt{G})_u=(\sqrt{E})_v$
so $(\cos\alpha)^2\cdot(\sqrt{E})_v=(\sqrt{E})_v$
Since $(\cos\alpha)^2<1$, we have $0=(\sqrt{E})_v=\frac1{2\sqrt{E}}E_v,0=(\sqrt{G})_u=\frac1{2\sqrt{G}}G_u$
so $E_v=G_u=0$
Is my proof correct?
